# How to update winform application without reinstallation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user login window application in C# which is installed in many systems,Now i have changed/updated new modification to the application. Then i have to uninstall the previous and install this new update application again in all systems.

Is there any method by which a updated can be performed to the previous application installed without uninstalling the previous application in the systems.ie user selects a update from a server location manually or automatically the installed application will check for update and install it

please help

Comment: Application distribution and upgrading is a very well-known problem to system administrators, which I think is more of a serverfault than stackoverflow question. If you want to build a selfupdating feature into your app, I think it still fits on SO, but please rephrase your question then.

Comment: ClickOnce can do it. I've also written a little app that checks the version no, installs the new version if needed then shells the main program. Obviously all the user shortcuts point to the launcher app.

Answer (score 2):

You got two easy solutions there:

1. At the installer level, you could use ClickOnce installer, it's nice and clean, however it will basically remove your old files and install the new ones (if they are ofc newer).
2. Another approach which I personally prefer: at the application level - divide your application into different modules (plugin style) thus creating seperate dlls for each activity - module. This way, when you load you software at startup, you can do a simple check to a ftp / svn / web service / even html page and verify the version of the dlls. 
   If the files on the server are newer then download the new ones before loading them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are lots of ways to arrange for an application to read an update.  Most usually this is done by having it read a small file on a server and then if there is a newer version offer to download it.  I did write my own at one time.  I checked a web address for a file containing the latest version and compared it to the version the user was running.  I then closed my app after shelling out to an updater app that downloaded the update, applied the file changes and restarted my app.  Now I use AppLife Update.  This provides all the tools needed to check for an update, download an incremental update and apply it.  It is payware but the basic version is not that expensive.

Of course you would need to release a version first that contained any update checking code.